# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor del elemento que ejecuta la funcion jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

El problema que me surge es por que estoy relacionando una base de datos el cual mediante un `while(){}` me devuelve determinados resultados.

De esto no hay problema pero tengo un link que me ejecuta una función que hace que aparezca una ventana modal que contiene un formulario para insertar datos relacionados con los registros consultados en la tabla anterior y quiero que me rellene un campo `hidden` con el id de dicho paciente de la tabla anterior.

El problema es que no puedo obtener el valor de id del elemento que en este caso está ejecutando la función y si  envió con el id del `<a>` siempre me dará el numero del primer elemento encontrado con dicho id y no del presionado.

Esta es parte de la función que llama la ventana modal que esta oculta con la cual en una parte quiero llenar un input llamado `#idd` con los datos de la url `<a id="link" onclick="modal();" title="<?php echo $mostrar['idpaciente']>" >` primero intente sacando el attr asi `$('#link').attr('title');`

Si tienen algun método mejor seria de mucha ayuda

```
var active = 1;

            function modal(){
                if (active == 1) {
                $('#modal').fadeIn(150);
                $('#caja').animate({
                    margin: '125px auto'
                }, 'fast');
                active = 0;
                $('#idd').val($(this).val());
                }else{
                $('#modal').fadeOut(150);
                $('#caja').animate({
                    margin: '0px auto'
                }, 'fast');
                active = 1;
                }
            } // SCRIP DE LOGGIN
```

Comment: Si lo que intentas es acceder a el elemento con el que se esta interactuando en ese momento solo utiliza $(this) con esto podrás acceder a todas sus propiedades.

Comment: @luis fernando si te fijas ya utilice el this pero no esta funcionando

Answer (score 1):

el tema aca esta en como se llama la funcion desde el elemento html, si lo haces enviando el parametro this deberia funcionar, tu tag terminaria viendose asi:

```
<a id="link" onclick="modal(this);" title="<?php echo $mostrar['idpaciente']>" >
```

De esta forma cuando atrapes el llamado a la funcion podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
function modal(sender){
  if (active) {

    $('#modal').fadeIn(150);
    $('#caja').animate({margin: '125px auto'}, 'fast');
    active = 0;

    $('#idd').val(sender.getAttribute("title"));
  }
  else{
    $('#modal').fadeOut(150);
    $('#caja').animate({margin: '0px auto'}, 'fast');
    active = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: eres un genio hermano estos detalles son los que debo aprender de javascript esto me sera muy util si tienes un titulo para este tipo de ejecuciones con el cual yo pueda seguir estudiándolas fuera un éxito gracias mil me funciono a la primera

Comment: Bueno no se si decirte que tienen un titulo pero basicamente son los "escuchadores" de eventos, podes leer al respecto en la [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp), o mas en profundidad en la [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Es lo que hace el navegador detras de las cortinas cuando escribis el onEvento.